# Exim SMTP server, reroute message based on Subject line (reroute to different SMTP)

Tags: email, smtp, exim

I have a IMAP/SMTP server (exim) that is running fine.

I connect several client applications to this (think Outloook desktop and the like).

What I would like to do is route some of the emails to a different SMTP server when they are being sent, think of it like this:

1, My SMTP server receives an email to send from for example Outlook Desktop. 2, If the email doesn't have a subject line that contains the word XX, send it through third-party SMTP server 3, If the email has a subject line that contains the word XX, use the regular SMTP server.

I'm sure I have phrased the question "wrong" since Im not very good when it comes to unix, but this seems like something that would work. I imagine that you can do some kind of "check" in exim (just like some kind of outgoing spam check).

Can this be done?

This was previously posted on stackoverflow, moved to superuser.